# Converting power of 10 to Knuth Arrow notation

Tags: exponentiation, big-numbers

I have this really big number $10^{1762613844998129336721604609} - 1$ which I want to represent in a more compact way. I know it's possible to convert these kind of numbers to Knuth arrow notation, but I have no idea how to do it. I tried finding ressources online, asking people I know but noone really knew how to do it.

It'd be very appreciated if you could guide me in a direction on how to approach this.

If it helps, the number can be represented as $10^{1207959552^{3}} - 1$

Comment: 10^{1762613844998129336721604609}−1=2^{1762613844998129336721604609}5^{1762613844998129336721604609}-1 and then a lot of factoring and wikipedia

Comment: Knuth arrow notated numbers are usually wastly larger than numbers like this , which can be well approximated by $10^{10^{27.2461571771}}$ and is already beaten by a power tower containing four tens. If you want to have an exact representation , you probably cannot do better than the representation you mentioned.

Comment: @ness To factor a number like this is utterly hopeless. Note that the given number has more than $10^{27}$ digits !

Comment: But maybe one can find $a<x<b$ with $a,b$ having relatively simple expressions in arrow notation and bound nicely our number instead.

Comment: Where this is coming from is this person told me this under a codegolf submission:

"Also assuming the estimated result is accurate, 6.3 * 10^72^5 / 96^3 is approximately 10^10^10^0.96786 = 10^^3.96786". 

This made me think I could easily convert my numbers

Comment: $(1)$ This equation is not correct. Your first expression is smaller than $10\uparrow \uparrow 3$, the second one vastly larger. $(2)$ You do not need Knut's arrow notation, the tetration notation "a $\uparrow \uparrow$ b" meaning a power tower of $b$ $a$'s is enough. Do you know that the humble $3\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3$ is already equal to $3\uparrow \uparrow (3^{27})$ ? Its magnitude is utterly incomprehensible.

Comment: There is no accepted version of $a\uparrow \uparrow b$ allowing a non-integer $b$.

Comment: So what the person told me was not right?

Comment: @peter iono, 10 mins with a calculator and paper shaves 2^{1762613844998129336721604609} down to 20 digits in the exponent. Someone who is adept with coding (not me) could write a program in 20 mins that uses ideas like 2^120=4^60=16^30=256^15=256*65536^7 etc. just pull out sets of primes till you can't and then move on.

Comment: @ness You forgot the "-1" at the end.

Comment: Moreover, the perfect power (even without $-1$) is too large , no computer can handlt it by using its concrete decimal expansion. $10^{27}$ digits is simply too much ! You can of course easily factor $10^n$ , but for this , you need no computer anyway , thee result is just $2^n\cdot 5^n$ , no matter how large $n$ is.

Comment: yes and then exponents in exponents or multiples etc. I only worked on the 2^ part, so no -1 needed... like 2*(256)^512 is a factor with 20 digits in the exponent after like 20 iterations.... which could be done much cheaper

Comment: @Jadefalke The suggested representation is only an approximation. And therefore, you can as well omit the "$-1$". For a reasonable approximation, I suggest $10^{10^{27}}$ , for the exact value there will be no more compact representation.

Comment: @ness My point was that the prime factorization of $10^n-1$ is hopeless for such a large $n$. We can of course omit the "-1" and factor the exponent, but this representation is not much more compact. The purpose of this question is anyway another , namely representing this number with Knut's up-arrow notation, which does not work well here. There won't be a power tower with equal entries giving a good approximation of this number.